# Process Affinity

Tags: winapi

Is it possible to programmatically either via the win32API (python) or via a command line option set the processor affinity for a process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a process handle, you can call the [SetProcessAffinityMask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686223(VS.85).aspx) Win32 API function to set the processor affinity for another process. Note that all the usual security restrictions are in effect, that is, you will probably only be able to change the process affinity for a process you own.

Answer (score 0):

In C/C++ you can use [SetThreadIdealProcessor()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686253(VS.85).aspx).  I have no idea if this is accessible in python.

```
DWORD processorId = 0;
SetThreadIdealProcessor(GetCurrentThread(),processorId);
```